# Is there an organization for server engineers to volunteer their expertise?

Tags: untagged

The recent events in Haiti got me interested in volunteering, and I as a professional computer guy I was hoping to volunteer in my own field - but opportunities seem to be slim.  Does anyone know of any organizations that are looking for computer people to volunteer their time and knowledge?

Comment: It may be worth contacting some of the charities, as they may be able to point you in the right direction. BTW, this really should be a wiki.

Comment: after looking at my last paycheck I think I am a volunteer... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeekCorps ( http://www.geekcorps.org/ ) is the only one I'm aware of.

Also, this was a Slashdot question a while back -- http://ask.slashdot.org/story/10/01/20/206249/How-Do-You-Volunteer-Professional-Services

Note that as many in the Slashdot article pointed out a computer/IT gig is likely to require a long-term commitment to a project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this counts, but it's the only one I know which is related, [UNV Online Volunteering Service](http://www.onlinevolunteering.org/en/vol/opportunity_search/?typ=5). Most of them are not really about *server stuff*.